# Why does LDAP work only for 64 bit but is slow for 32 bit? Why did my 1 line SQLNET.ORA change fix my issue?

Tags: ldap, oracle

I have two Oracle 12.1 clients installed on my laptop, a 32 install and a 64 bit install. The configurations were the same for both. My SQLNET.ORA file was set up to specify to first use OID and then fail over to use my TNSAMES.OA file. The contents of the pair of files were as follows below.

My problem was that although my 64 bit client worked fine, when I connected using the 32 bit client it took about 2 minutes to make the connection. SSIS (Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services) can only use the 32 bit client and trying to develop an SSIS package using the 32 bit client was a horribly slow experience until I figured out how to resolve  but would like to understand why my change worked.

--SQLNET.ORA FILE:

```
# This file is actually generated by netca. But if customers choose to 
# install "Software Only", this file wont exist and without the native 
# authentication, they will not be able to connect to the database on NT.
names.directory_path=(LDAP, TNSNAMES)
NAMES.DEFAULT_DOMAIN = cigna.com
# SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NTS)
```

--FILE LDAP.ORA

```
DIRECTORY_SERVERS= (oid.gtm.internal.mycompany.com:3060)
DEFAULT_ADMIN_CONTEXT = "dc=mycompany,dc=com"
DIRECTORY_SERVER_TYPE = OID
```

--TNSNAMES.ORA

```
Contents not shown
```

The 64 client worked find so, I left the 3 files alone. For the 32 bit client that connected slow, I modified SQLNET.ORA line from "names.directory_path=(LDAP, TNSNAMES)" to "names.directory_path=(TNSNAMES, LDAP)" in the 32 bit version, to go straight to my TNSNAMES.ORA file to resolve the end point instead of tring to communicate with the LDAP server first.

So, it seems that there was a delay trying to communicate with the LDAP server, oid.gtm.internal.mycompany.com, for some reason, but only with the 32 bit client. When I inverted the order, it was fine for 32 bit.

My question is this: Why would it work for 64 bit but not for 32 bit and the client otherwise work?

**Update**
My windows PATH variable puts the 64 bit Oracle folder first. When I open a cmd window and tnsping, the 64 bit client is used and says "Used LDAP adapter to resolve the alias" in 60 msec. If I create a batch file to modify the PATH variable for the cmd session to put the 32 Oracle Client folder first and then CD into the 32 bit bin folder C:\oracle_12102_32bit\product\12102_32bit\CLIENT_1\bin before attemmpting the tnsping, it pauses a long time and then says that it "Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias" even though the SQLNET.ORA said to use LDAP first. In this 32 test, it says that it used the TNSNAMES to resolve regardless of whether my SQLNET.ORA says to use LDAP or TNSNAMES first. If LDAP is first, it must be failing and taking a long time to do so. if I switch the order to say TNSNAMES first, then LDAP, it is fast.

So I guess the question is why does LDAP only work for 64 bit if I have copies of the same 3 files in the 32 folders? Someone gave me a line to add to - I think it was the SQLNET.ORA file to add logging to a TRACE (*.TRC) file to see why but I could not find any recent ones on my PC. (I used VOID TOOLS SEARCH EVERYTHING to quickly search my whole PC for TRACE files). I can't remember what the exact statement ones that I since removed but it was setting some LOGGING_LEVEL to ADMIN or something like that..

Why would LDAP fail for 32 bit but not 64 bit?

Comment: What does TNSPing show? Both of them.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Please see my update.

Comment: What is ORACLE_HOME defined as? See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25216290/installing-oracle-32-bit-client-on-windows-server-already-running-64-bit-oracle/25229914

Comment: My 32 bit ORACLE_HOME variable, stored in Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\ORACLE\KEY_OraClient12Home1_32bit\ORACLE_HOME, is set to C:\oracle_12102_32bit\product\12102_32bit\CLIENT_1. My 64 bit ORACLE_HOME variable, stored in Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_OraClient12Home1\ORACLE_HOME, is set to C:\oracle_12102_64bit\product\12102_64bit\CLIENT_1

Comment: Are there environment variables for ORACLE_HOME?

Comment: @greg, No. Windows uses the registry for this variable. There's no USER or SYSTEM environmental variable on the machine called ORACLE_HOME. Thanks.